# Get file from internet, load into memory and take each line into an array

Tags: node.js

I am looking at getting this text file from the internet loaded into my nodejs server (into memory):

http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

I want to extract each line and place it into an array which I can search later, but I have not been able to get it to work.

I have tried using request, fs, and readline:

```
var request = require('request');
var lineCnt = 0;
var result = [];

request.get('http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var csv = body;
        var fs = require('fs');
        var readline = require('readline');
        readline.createInterface({
                   input: fs.createReadStream(body),
                   terminal: false
           }).on('line', function(line) {
              if(lineCnt == 0){ //do nothing skip the first line}
              else{
                  result.push(line);
               }
               lineCnt = lineCnt + 1; //increment
       });
    }
});
```

It does not work though as the array is empty. I get the following error:

```
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '# Version 2017041700, Last Updated Mon Apr 17 07:07:01 2017 UTC ... [the rest of the file]'
```

Comment: where is your body defined?

Comment: @RaviShankar It is defined as one of the arguments in the function

Comment: Not sure why the downvote

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't even need a module like `request` for this. However what you should do instead if you're going to use `request` is to not use the "buffered callback" feature but get the response stream and pass that to `readline.createInterface()`. For example:

```
request.get('http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt')
       .on('response', (response) => {
  if (response.statusCode === 200) {
    var readline = require('readline');
    readline.createInterface({
      input: response,
      terminal: false
    }).on('line', function(line) {
      if(lineCnt == 0){ //do nothing skip the first line}
      else{
        result.push(line);
      }
      lineCnt = lineCnt + 1; //increment
    });
  }
}).on('error', ...);
```